# SonarQube Stopped with Error

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I am new to SonarQube. I installed it to analyze my code on jenkins. When I edited properties file and run start command, the process stopped shortly after I started it. I went to web.log file and got this message:

```
[o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed: Current version is too old. Please upgrade to Long Term Support version firstly.
```

I have java-8, mysql 14.14 and SonarQube 6.5.

What is it actually complaining? What is too old?

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947417/messageexception-current-version-is-too-old-please-upgrade-to-long-term-suppor

Comment: Exactly, we had the same issue and it was solved using the same method! Thanks@nullpointer

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that an older version of sonarqube had connected to database. Somehow the database was registered as older version. I delete and recreate the database and the problem was solved.